# Bullet Physics Headers : No such file or directory

Tags: physics-engine, bulletphysics

When I try to use a header file in my project ( I created the .a files and linking before), I get the next error:

```
fatal error: <bullet header.h> : No such file or directory
```

I create the libraries .a following this tutorial:

http://vgamec.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/instalar-bullet-physics-para-codeblocks.html

Does anyone know why I can not use the library?

P.D. I use Codeblocks 12.11 and the compiler GCC version 4.7.1, 32 bit.

Comment: The include files are located in 'src' of the SDK folder, so put that in your search directories for the compiler. Also, if you haven't decompressed it, you should probably look in to doing that.

Answer (score 0):

BulletPhysics has no such header file. `bullet header.h`

Mistake is in code that includes that file.

Show code that `#include`